# Can i point to a specific location in a function?

Tags: c++, function

Say i have this main int

```
int main();
{
 cout << " Hello! ";

 function1();

 cout << " BYE!";
}
```

Is there a way to make it so once im done with the function1 to make it just point to the top of 'cout << " BYE!";' so i dont have to go through Hello again? Basically i want to just point the end of function1 to the top of Bye. is this possible without ifs and all that?

Comment: What do you mean by "point to" the top of `cout << " BYE!"`?  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What you're asking is what exactly happening in your code.

Comment: You keep writing *"point to"*. We haven't a clue what you mean. Do you wish to repeatedly execute a part of your code? Do you wish to jump execution into the middle of your function from somewhere in the same function? From another function? Be specific about what you with to achieve---be more than specific be pedantic and redundant. That way we'll have a better chance of "getting it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when ever a function is completely executed. The c++ pointer tries to execute the statement which comes after the function. However if you want to point to some specific location you can use the statement

Goto  to go to a specific label let us say  abc:

```
int main();
{
 cout << " Hello! ";

 function1();
Goto label
...
....
...

label :
 cout << " BYE!";
}
```

however i dont recommend this.

Comment: How can i do that to another function?

Comment: just put different labels at different places and use the command goto to jump to that label location. but this is not a recommended way

Comment: @mystycs please post a sensible example of **what you're trying to do** in your question. Otherwise you'll get lots of answers that don't answer the question you didn't ask.

Answer (score 1):

This code already does that. Try running it!

(You will have to get rid of the semicolon after `main()`)

Comment: Well say i have a buch of functions how can i just point it to something if i choose to? To a location with in an int any location that wish?

Comment: What you are asking makes no sense. Please edit your question to provide a better example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`so i dont have to go through Hello again`

What you say makes no sense. It won't go back to Hello again, why do you think it would? That is not how things work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say you want to point to a specific location, you mean you want a first-class value that you can pass, store, etc, like a function pointer.

If that's the case, you might be interested in [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), which provide this kind of behavior.

It's generally not possible to construct this functionality in a language that does not already have it; you need help from the environment.  For C/C++, you might use [System V contexts](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/System-V-contexts.html).  I'm peering around for a library to abstract this away further for you, but nothing's jumping out.